# How to restart \footnote numbering every page

Tags: latex, footnotes

I have more than 9 footnotes, so I need to restart the footnote numbering. I know that I can force that adding [1] in the 10th item, but I want something automatic.

How can I do it? Adding some word every page..¿?

Comment: What do you mean you have to restart the footnote numbering ?

Comment: Every page I add a new footnote automatically is [1], then [2]....and so on. Next page, again [1] ....

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/footnote-counter-would-like-to-restart-from-1-each-page

Answer (score 31):

One solution is the **`perpage`** package, that provides a general mechanism for resetting counters per page. Put the command `\usepackage{perpage}` and `\MakePerPage{footnote}` into your document preamble, immediately after the `\documentclass` line and before the `\begin{document}` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command
\begin{document}
```

The interface is pretty simple: `\MakePerPage{footnote}` will do the job. If you want to restart the counter at something other than 1 (for example to avoid something in the LaTeX footnote symbol list), you can use: `\MakePerPage[2]{footnote}`. It’s a first-rate package, small and efficient.

Reference: TeX FAQ entry [Footnotes numbered “per page”](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footnpp)

Answer (score 6):

Reset the `footnote` counter, or make it reset by page:

- [Master and slave counters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset)
- [Footnotes numbered “per page”](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footnpp)